# AngularJS e2e test Protractor: Failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

I have an application up and running correctly in a browser, realized on AngularJS. But when I run the e2e tests with Protractor, the following error is thrown:

> Stacktrace:
>        UnknownError: {"errorMessage":"[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module criteriaManager due to:\nError:
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module filearts.dragDrop
>   due to:\nError: [$injector:nomod] Module 'filearts.dragDrop' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second
>   argument.\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.17/$injector/nomod?p0=filearts.dragDrop\n

This is my app.js module dependencies:

```
var criteriaManager = angular.module('criteriaManager', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'config', 'lbServices', 'dndLists', 
                                                         'ngMessages', 'ngTable', 'ngTagsInput', 'filearts.dragDrop', 'ngCookies']);
```

Which is not working for the e2e test.

When I remove the library DragDrop:

```
var criteriaManager = angular.module('criteriaManager', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'config', 'lbServices', 'dndLists', 
                                                         'ngMessages', 'ngTable', 'ngTagsInput', 'ngCookies']);
```

Then it works fine.

I don’t understand why all modules/libraries of my app.js are correctly injected when running the e2e test, except for the Drag and Drop one. The library that causes the error can be found at: 
https://github.com/ggoodman/angular-drag-drop

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The problem has been partially solved by hacking one of the files in the library mentioned above (src/angular-drag-drop.js). Changes: Removed require(...css) and var Angular = require("angular");    Replaced "Angular" by "angular" everywhere in the file.